Azure AD should support logging into the callback url in Blazor
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@layout EmptyLayout

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject ILogger<Authentication> Logger

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="OnLogInSucceeded" OnLogOutSucceeded="OnLogOutSucceeded">
    <LoggingIn>
        <SplashScreen Text="Logging In..."></SplashScreen>
    </LoggingIn>
    <CompletingLoggingIn>
        <SplashScreen Text="Completing Login"></SplashScreen>
    </CompletingLoggingIn>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    private async Task OnLogInSucceeded(RemoteAuthenticationState remoteAuthenticationState)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLoginSucceeded start", nameof(Authentication));
        var authenticationState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: authenticationState retrieved", nameof(Authentication));
        if (authenticationState.User.Identity is not null && authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: user identity is not null and user is authenticated", nameof(Authentication));
            if (authenticationState.User.Claims.All(c => c.Type != "role"))
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: user claims does not have any role types setting return url of remoteAuthenticationState to unauthorized", nameof(Authentication));
                remoteAuthenticationState.ReturnUrl = "/unauthorized";
            }
        }
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLoginSucceeded end", nameof(Authentication));
    }

    private void OnLogOutSucceeded(RemoteAuthenticationState remoteAuthenticationState)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLogoutSucceeded start", nameof(Authentication));
        remoteAuthenticationState.ReturnUrl = "/authentication/login";
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: set remoteAuthenticationState Return Url to /authentication/login", nameof(Authentication));
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLogoutSucceeded end", nameof(Authentication));
    }
}

This is my blazer code, client bookmarked the URL as
http://localhost:5300/authentication/login-callback#code=0.AVoAZNoWcXd0WUyrFv2LtmlwSUir_qkyXOROvH9M36rkDGrXALs.AgABBAIAAAApTwJmzXqdR4BN2miheQMYAgDs_wUA9P-
How can my application still support it, as of now it is staying in loading with spinner.
I have tried with
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="OnLogInSucceeded" OnLogOutSucceeded="OnLogOutSucceeded">
    <LoggingIn>
        <SplashScreen Text="Logging In..."></SplashScreen>
    </LoggingIn>
    <CompletingLoggingIn>
        <SplashScreen Text="Completing Login"></SplashScreen>
    </CompletingLoggingIn>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (Action == "login-callback")
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await CompleteLogin();
        }
    }

    private async Task CompleteLogin()
    {
        var authenticationState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        if (authenticationState.User.Identity is not null && authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (authenticationState.User.Claims.All(c => c.Type != "role"))
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/unauthorized");
            }
            else
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Navigation.NavigateToLogin("/authentication/login");
        }
    }
}

I would like to is there any better way to achieve it or is it the right path.

How can your client run the localhost URL ?

actually it is like this https://my.client.com/authentication/login-callback/#code=fjdasklfjdksalfjdkafkdlsajkldsa

In Blazor WebAssembly application to bookmark the login callback url make sure that handling the login-callback action appropriately.
I used NavigationManager to handle redirects after login success or failure.
Below is modified code of the Authentication.razor:
@page "/authentication/{Action}"
@using BlazorApp32.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@layout EmptyLayout
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject ILogger<Authentication> Logger
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="OnLogInSucceeded" OnLogOutSucceeded="OnLogOutSucceeded">
    <LoggingIn>
        <SplashScreen Text="Logging In..."></SplashScreen>
    </LoggingIn>
    <CompletingLoggingIn>
        <SplashScreen Text="Completing Login"></SplashScreen>
    </CompletingLoggingIn>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (Action == "login-callback")
        {
            await CompleteLogin();
        }
    }
    private async Task CompleteLogin()
    {
        var authenticationState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        if (authenticationState.User?.Identity != null && authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (authenticationState.User.Claims.All(c => c.Type != "role"))
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/unauthorized");
            }
            else
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Navigation.NavigateToLogin("/authentication/login");
        }
    }
    private async Task OnLogInSucceeded(RemoteAuthenticationState remoteAuthenticationState)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLoginSucceeded start", nameof(Authentication));

        if (remoteAuthenticationState == null)
        {
            Logger.LogError("{Component}: remoteAuthenticationState is null", nameof(Authentication));
            return;
        }

        var authenticationState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        if (authenticationState == null)
        {
            Logger.LogError("{Component}: authenticationState is null", nameof(Authentication));
            return;
        }
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: authenticationState retrieved", nameof(Authentication));

        if (authenticationState.User?.Identity != null && authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: user identity is not null and user is authenticated", nameof(Authentication));
            if (authenticationState.User.Claims.All(c => c.Type != "role"))
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: user claims does not have any role types setting return url of remoteAuthenticationState to unauthorized", nameof(Authentication));
                remoteAuthenticationState.ReturnUrl = "/unauthorized";
            }
        }
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLoginSucceeded end", nameof(Authentication));
    }
    private void OnLogOutSucceeded(RemoteAuthenticationState remoteAuthenticationState)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLogoutSucceeded start", nameof(Authentication));
        
        if (remoteAuthenticationState == null)
        {
            Logger.LogError("{Component}: remoteAuthenticationState is null", nameof(Authentication));
            return;
        }
        remoteAuthenticationState.ReturnUrl = "/authentication/login";
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: set remoteAuthenticationState Return Url to /authentication/login", nameof(Authentication));
        Logger.LogInformation("{Component}: OnLogoutSucceeded end", nameof(Authentication));
    }
}

App.razor:
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not Found</PageTitle>
            <h1>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</h1>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

For client purpose I deployed to azure app service and bookmark the login callback as shown below.

And It successfully login to the account.
Azure App service Output:


@visweswar .penti Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
